# Is it necessary for a Lambda to delete messages from an SQS queue after processing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm looking at the the AWS SQS documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/ReceiveMessage.html#receive-sqs-message

My understanding is that we need to delete the message using `AmazonSQSClient.DeleteMessage()` once we're done processing it, but is this necessary when we're working with an SQS triggered Lambda?

I'm testing with a Lambda function that's triggered by an `SQSEvent`, and unless I'm mistaken, it appears that if the Lambda function runs to completion without throwing any errors, the message does NOT return to the SQS queue. If this is true, the I would rather avoid making that unnecessary call to `AmazonSQSClient.DeleteMessage()`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003706/aws-lambda-not-removing-messages-from-the-queue) is a similar question from 2019 with the top answer saying that the SDK does not delete messages automatically and that they need to be explicitly deleted within the code. I'm wondering if anything has changed since then.

Thoughts?

Comment: Minor note on terminology. In the case of the Lambda function failing to process the SQS messages, those messages aren't *returned* to the SQS queue. Instead, they become visible again (once their visibility timeout occurs). Those messages never left the SQS queue.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The key here is that you are using the [AWS Lambda integration with SQS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html). In that instance AWS Lambda handles retrieving the messages from the queue (making them available via the `event` object), and automatically deletes the message from the queue for you if the Lambda function returns a success status. It will not delete the message from the queue if the Lambda function throws an error.

When using AWS Lambda integration with SQS you should not be using the AWS SDK to interact with the SQS queue at all.

---

**Update:**
Lambda now supports [partial batch failure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#services-sqs-batchfailurereporting) for SQS whereby the Lambda function can return a list of failed messages and only those will become visible again.

Comment: There's one scenario in which you might want the Lambda to interact directly with SQS, and that's if you're processing a batch of messages and, in preparation for the potential failure to process some subset of those messages, you want to be sure that the successfully-processed messages do not become visible again in SQS. Your Lambda function can explicitly delete each SQS message as it is successfully processed in this case. Or you can make use of middleware, such as [middy](https://github.com/middyjs/middy/tree/master/packages/sqs-partial-batch-failure), to do this for you.

Comment: Nice answer but please can you add a reference to AWS docs, showing that in case of "lambda integration with sqs" the lambda deletes automatically the message incase it returns a success status? I can't find it anywhere in AWS docs.

Comment: @Mercury it's in the second paragraph on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

Comment: Following the comment @jarmod there is a video on this topic here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zysQqxgj0I&t=1263s

Comment: Small update here: Lambda now supports [partial batch failure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#services-sqs-batchfailurereporting) for SQS whereby the Lambda function can return a list of failed messages snd only those will become visible again.

Comment: _Lambda function returns a success status_ - what exactly should you return from the lambda to indicate a successful status?

Comment: @MetroSmurf see the "Success and failure conditions" section in the documentation I linked: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html Depending on the programming language a simple, valid JSON response may be enough.

Comment: @MarkB - I've read that doc like 10x's - nothing there indicates what AWS accepts as valid. The best I can tell, at least for nodejs, is to simply exit the lambda upon success.

Comment: @MetroSmurf the part of the docs I told you to refer to specifically say you can return a `null` response or an empty JSON response like `{}` from your NodeJS code to indicate a success.

Comment: @MarkB - thanks. I had read that and assumed those return types were specific to batch processes. I suppose it makes sense that simply existing the lambda w/o an error is the same as returning null, i.e., success. Thanks.

Comment: Returning `{}` was the missing part for me, all my messages despite not throwing errors, were being reprocessed after visibility timeout, and eventually going to DLQ, just because my function was not returning `{}` nor `null` to indicate success, made me waste days troubleshooting what was wrong. When I worked with the .NET SDK there was not such requirement, a message would succeed as long as you didn't throw an exception, it'd be nice if they did the same with Javascript SDK.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, otherwise the next time you ask for a set of messages, you will get the same messages back - maybe not on the next call, but eventually you will. You likely don't want to keep processing the same set of messages over and over.