# How does SQS keep track of messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a pretty standard setup of feeding SQS to Lambda.  The lambda reads the message and makes a web request to a defined endpoint.

If I encounter an exception during processing of the SQS message that is due to the form of the message then I put the message on a dead letter queue.

If I encounter an error with the web request, I put the message back on the feeding queue to make the HTTP request at a later time.

This seems to work fine, but we just ran into an issue where an HTTP endpoint was down for 4 days and the feeding queue dropped the message.  I imagine this has something to do with the retention period setting of the queue.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to know, in the lambda, how many times a message has been replayed?
2. How did the feeder queue know that the message that was re-enqueued was the same as the one that was originally put on the queue?
3. I'm currently not explicitly deleting a message off the queue.  Not having that, hasn't seemed to cause any issues, no re-processing of messages or anything.  Should I be explicitly deleting them?

Comment: What is your "standard setup of feeding SQS to Lambda"?

Comment: On the topic of SQS message retention, per the docs: "You can configure the Amazon SQS message retention period to a value from 1 minute to 14 days. The default is 4 days. Once the message retention quota is reached, your messages are automatically deleted."

Comment: Also be aware of this KB article on [preventing duplicate message processing](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-process-sqs-messages/).

Comment: When you "put the message on a dead letter queue", are you saying that your Lambda function creates a new message in that queue, or do you let SQS move the message to that queue? Also, when you say "I put the message back on the feeding queue", are you saying that you write a new message to the SQS queue, or do you simply return an error code and let SQS keep the existing message on the queue?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - I create a new message and put it on the dead letter queue.  SQS will move it after the retention period expires, but I know when a message is malformed during processing so I create a new message and move that to the dead letter queue.  

Yes, I create a new message and put it back on the SQS queue.  My lamda returns 200 in all instances, so I believe that should remove the message from the queue.

Comment: @jarmod - What I mean by standard, is SQS triggers Lambda with default settings (4 day retention on messages in queue).  I'm aware of the retention policy that drops it into the dead letter automatically.  I was saying that during processing of the message, if I recognize that it is a malformed message, I create a new message and put it on the dead letter queue explicitly.

Comment: Typically your Lambda function doesn't put SQS messages back onto the SQS queue. Instead, the Lambda function fails (returns an error or times out) and the batch of SQS messages that it should have processed become visible again in the queue (they never left the queue) after their visibility timeout ends. If your Lambda function succeeds then the batch of messages that it processed are presumed to have been successful and the messages are deleted from the SQS queue by the Lambda service (not by your code, although you can explicitly do this if you need to).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65293234/is-it-necessary-for-a-lambda-to-delete-messages-from-an-sqs-queue-after-processi

Comment: If you want to know how many times a given message has been delivered to a Lambda function so you can track/detect retries then see one solution [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-sqs-dead-letter-queues-to-replay-messages/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal process would be:

- The AWS Lambda function is triggered, with the message(s) passed via the `event` parameter
- If the Lambda function **successfully processes** the message(s), it should return a 'success' code (200) and the message is automatically removed from the queue
- If the Lambda function is **unable to process** the message, it should return a 'failure' code (eg 400) and Amazon SQS will automatically attempt to re-process the message (unless it has exceeded the retry count)
- If the Lambda function **fails** (eg due to a timeout), Amazon SQS will automatically attempt to re-process the message (unless it has exceeded the retry count)
- If a message has **exceeded its retry count**, Amazon SQS will move the message to the **Dead Letter Queue**

To answer your questions:

1. If you wish to take responsibility for these activities yourself, you can use the `ApproximateReceiveCount` attribute on the message. In the request, it appears that you should add `AttributeNames=['ApproximateReceiveCount']`, but the documentation is a bit contradictory. You might need to use `All` instead.
2. Since you are sending a new message to the queue, Amazon SQS is **not** aware that it is the same message. The message is *not* 're-enqueued' since it is a new message.
3. When your Lambda function returns 'success' (200), the message is being deleted off the queue for you.

You might consider using the standard functionality for retries and Dead Letter Queues rather than implementing that logic yourself.